# Apache POI 3.16 creates invalid files when run inside Matlab

Tags: java, matlab, apache-poi

I'm attempting to use Apache POI 3.16 from inside Matlab R2019b on macOS 10.14 to create Excel files programmatically. I can get it to run, but the files it creates are invalid: some of the XML elements inside the OOXML files inside the `.xlsx` file are missing their `xmlns` attributes, and Excel doesn't like that. Does anyone know why in the world this is happening?

I'm afraid I'm stuck on POI 3.16 or older due to dependency conflicts with other JARs shipped with Matlab.

I have loaded the POI jars on to my dynamic javaclasspath in Matlab:

```
>> javaclasspath -dynamic

        DYNAMIC JAVA PATH

    /Users/janke/local/repos/janklab/lib/java-ext/postgresql-42.2.9.jar                         
    /Users/janke/local/repos/janklab/lib/java/swingexplorer-1.6.0/swexpl.jar                    
    /Users/janke/local/repos/janklab/lib/java/swingexplorer-1.6.0/swag.jar                      
    /Users/janke/local/repos/janklab/lib/java/poi-3.16-dependencies/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar          
    /Users/janke/local/repos/janklab/lib/java/poi-3.16-dependencies/curvesapi-1.04.jar          
    /Users/janke/local/repos/janklab/lib/java/poi-3.16-dependencies/commons-logging-1.2.jar     
    /Users/janke/local/repos/janklab/lib/java/poi-3.16-dependencies/commons-collections4-4.1.jar
    /Users/janke/local/repos/janklab/lib/java/poi-3.16-dependencies/commons-codec-1.10.jar      
    /Users/janke/local/repos/janklab/lib/java/poi-3.16/poi-scratchpad-3.16.jar                  
    /Users/janke/local/repos/janklab/lib/java/poi-3.16/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.16.jar               
    /Users/janke/local/repos/janklab/lib/java/poi-3.16/poi-ooxml-3.16.jar                       
    /Users/janke/local/repos/janklab/lib/java/poi-3.16/poi-excelant-3.16.jar                    
    /Users/janke/local/repos/janklab/lib/java/poi-3.16/poi-examples-3.16.jar                    
    /Users/janke/local/repos/janklab/lib/java/poi-3.16/poi-3.16.jar
```

Here's my little test Matlab program:

```
function createHelloWorldXls

wkbk = org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
sheet = wkbk.createSheet("Hello");
row = sheet.createRow(0);
cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue("Hello, World!");
ostr = java.io.FileOutputStream("HelloFromMatlab.xlsx");
wkbk.write(ostr);
ostr.close;
```

When I try to open `HelloFromMatlab.xlsx` in Excel 16.33, I get the following error:

> Alert
>
> Excel cannot open the file 'HelloFromMatlab.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

Here's the equivalent program I wrote in plain Java, and ran against the same Apache POI 3.16 library:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class HelloWorldExcel {

    public static void createHelloWorldExcelFile() throws IOException {
        Workbook wkbk = new XSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet sheet = wkbk.createSheet("Hello");
        Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue("Hello, World!");
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("Hello.xlsx");
        wkbk.write(out);
        out.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        try {
            createHelloWorldExcelFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

That one works.

If I unzip the two files and compare them, I can see that some of the elements in the one produced from Matlab are lacking `xmlns` namespace attributes:

```
diff -r Hello HelloFromMatlab
diff -r Hello/[Content_Types].xml HelloFromMatlab/[Content_Types].xml
2,4c2,3
< <Types xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types">
[...]
> <Types>
[...]
< <Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
[...]
> <Relationships>
[...]
< <Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
[...]
> <Relationships>
```

If I manually edit the .xlsx file to add those `xmlns` namespace attributes, then it works, and Excel happily opens it.

What the heck?

Comment: Apache POI 3.16 is pretty old, and there have been a bunch of XML-related fixes since then, including workarounds for broken XML runtimes. Maybe try an upgrade to the latest version of POI, and see if that solves it?

Comment: `Apache poi` uses `javax.xml.*` and `org.w3c.dom.*` for `XML` creation. Looks as if your `matlab` uses versions of those which are different form those a default `JRE` uses. Note, I am not using `matlab`, so this is only a hint.

Comment: @Gagravarr: Sadly, I cannot upgrade POI any further than 3.16. The Matlab runtime ships with a bunch of JARs in its JRE environment, including some of POI's dependencies; POI 3.17 and later are not compatible with the set of dependency JARs bundled with Matlab. (I've already contacted MathWorks support and asked them to upgrade or remove these JARs, but that'll probably take years to happen.)

Comment: @AxelRichter: Here's a list of the Java JARs that Matlab R2019b ships with: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14684wWyS9FnS-MYD56ISJdmw9Csdymhs7GB-9nbeZz8/edit?usp=sharing. I don't see metadata that indicates those packages specifically, but there's `xml-apis.jar`, `xml-apis-ext.jar`, and `xercesImpl.jar` files in there, which sound related. Would those be it? (And it's using Oracle JRE 1.8.0_202-b08, if that matters.) If those are it, I might be able to override them in my Matlab process's Java `CLASSPATH`.

Comment: Using `Java JRE 8` there is no need for `xml-apis.jar`, `xml-apis-ext.jar`, and `xercesImpl.jar` because all `XML` related stuff is included in `JRE` already. So I suspect those `jar`s are old and outdated. See https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N101E6: "These libraries were required with Java 5 and lower, but are not actually required with spec-compliant Java 6 implementations, so try removing those libraries from your classpath. If this is not possible, try upgrading to a newer version of those jar files."

Comment: @AxelRichter: Ooh, good lead! I'll see what I can do to remove them. Meanwhile, I'm reporting that as a bug to MathWorks (creators of Matlab).

Comment: I haven't been able to fully confirm yet because it's hard to change the Java configuration of Matlab for its bundled JARs, but it does look to me like this you were right about the problem. My workaround is to just open up the generated file and munge the XML tags to be correct using some regexes. MathWorks says they're not going to fix it since I have a workaround and they're conservative about changing their Java stuff.